# C# Puma.Net The library dibapi.dll could not be found

Tags: c#, dll

I've got some issues running Puma.Net. I've got all the functions looking fine in the code but when it comes this point:

```
Value = pumaPage.RecognizeToString();
```

It then gives an error saying the library dibapi.dll can't be found. But I just can't even add it as a reference it says something like

> Can't add reference  Make sure the file is accessible and that it is a assembly or Com-Component.

So I gave it all the rights it needs to be read, write & executed. I even gave it full controll on all the users but it just won't work.

Maybe I made a mistake somewhere so here is the full code of the programm.

```
static void Main()
    {
        string Image = "V:/Test_images/value.PNG";

        Console.WriteLine("Running the Program!");

        var pumaPage = new PumaPage(Image);
        string Value;

        using (pumaPage)
        {
            pumaPage.FileFormat = PumaFileFormat.RtfAnsi;
            pumaPage.EnableSpeller = false;
            pumaPage.Language = PumaLanguage.Digits;

            Value = pumaPage.RecognizeToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Value is" + Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I've added the Puma.Net dll and "using Puma.Net;" so it should work. Does someone got any idea what could be wrong?

Here is also the errormessage that appears all the time.
[The Error Message which appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJbRz.png)
If you need a translation just tell me.

Btw it is a Console Application and I would love to keep it that way. If it is not possible then I can also try to use turn it into a Form Application but that's a whole new part for me so it could take a while to get into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy dibapi.dll to the output folder as described in the documentation:

Steps to add Puma.NET to your project:
1. Add reference to Puma.Net.dll;
2. Make sure that after project building the output folder (i.e. bin\Debug or bin\Release)
contains files Puma.Net.dll and puma.interop.dll. If the last is not present (IDE didn’t
copy it) copy it to the folder manually;
3. Copy dibapi.dll to the output folder;

Comment: When native DLLs used by .NET assemblies need to be copied, I usually solve that by adding them to the project (not reference, but add as file), and then setting the native DLL file's "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".

Comment: Thank you a thousand times for answering my question TwT
Thanks a lot. You just gave me like a push through for which I was to stupid to find that documentation.